# Lista desplegable con opción de búsqueda

Tags: html, angularjs, select

Tengo una lista desplegable declarada de la siguiente forma, tiene dentro 2 grupos, Perros y Gatos, ambas listas se muestran en el mismo desplegable.

Y sería posible añadir el input donde escribir para filtrar el desplegable, dentro del desplegable en la primera opción?

```
<label>Perros/Gatos (*)</label>
                    <div class="customClass">
                        <select ng-model="mascotas.type" 
                                ui-select2="ui-select2" 
                                required>
                               <optgroup label="Perros">
                                <option ng-repeat="p in perros" value="{{p.name}}">{{p.label}}</option>
                            </optgroup>
                            <optgroup label="Gatos">
                                <option ng-repeat="g in gatos" value="{{g.name}}">{{g.label}}</option>
                            </optgroup>                           
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Es posible, poder filtrar los String del desplegable de según vaya escribiendo?

Answer (score 0):

Para ello tendrías que utilizar el pipe de filter sobre el np-repeat utilizando un input tipo text como texto de filtro.

Ejemplo rápido:

```
<input ng-model="texto-filtro"/>

<label>Perros/Gatos (*)</label>
<div class="customClass">
 <select ng-model="mascotas.type" ui-select2="ui-select2" required>
  <optgroup label="Perros">
  <option ng-repeat="p in perros | filter:texto-filtro" value="{{p.name}}"> 
  {{p.label}}</option>
 </optgroup>
 <optgroup label="Gatos">
  <option ng-repeat="g in gatos | filter:texto-filtro" value="{{g.name}}"> 
  {{g.label}}</option>
 </optgroup>                           
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias te comento en cuanto lo pruebe

Comment: pero tengo 2 ng repeat 1 por optgroup